# Create operationId and use it through all request lifetime

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

In ASP.NET Core, there is an option to decorate log with custom value generated at the beginning and then all logs within given request would contain that information.

For example:

```cs
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    using (LogContext.PushProperty("CorrelationId", Guid.NewGuid()))
    {     
        await next.Invoke(context);
    }
});
```

I have an API project with controllers and it references business logic project. In the business layer, I have services classes, for example `GetTime` service (just a silly example).

Is it possible to configure ASP.NET Core in an easy way so that I may have access from that `GetTime` service to the property that was created at the beginning of the request globally (like in logging context?)

What would be the best way to do that?

I would like have access to it from all classes, `GetTime` is only an example service class. I know that I can probably implement some kind of per Request class that implements an interface like `IRequestMetadata` and inject it into all classes but I'm not sure how to do that and maybe there is a better option?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to configure ASP.NET Core in an easy way so that I may have access from that GetTime service to the property that was created at the beginning of the request globally (like in logging context?)
>
> What would be the best way to do that?

Yes, you can use `AsyncLocal<T>` to do that. I recommend setting the async local value in a middleware, and then resetting it to its original value / unsetting it at the end of that middleware. You can do this by writing an `IDisposable` type that unsets the value.

> I know that I can probably implement some kind of per Request class that implements an interface like IRequestMetadata and inject it into all classes but I'm not sure how to do that and maybe there is a better option?

In most cases, I would argue in favor of the per-request DI-injected dependency. The problem with `AsyncLocal<T>` is that it is an *implicit* dependency, which is just harder to deal with and reason about. Yes, it magically works, but does so at the expense of code maintainability. With injected dependencies, there's no magic.

A decent middle ground is something like the `IHttpContextAccessor` interface. It's actually implemented with an `AsyncLocal<T>` under the hood, but end-user code cannot access the `AsyncLocal<T>` directly; it has to inject an `IHttpContextAccessor`, making the dependency explicit.

Comment: thanks, " In most cases, I would argue in favor of the per-request DI-injected dependency" -> ok I agree but when then would be the best way to configure that per request dependency? Write middleWare for it?

Comment: @beseus: If your per-request data can be generated at any time (e.g., a unique GUID for the request), then you can just create a type and register it as scoped in the DI. If your per-request data needs to be set at a specific time, then use a middleware to write an AsyncLocal<T> at the appropriate time, and create another type that reads that AsyncLocal, and register that other type as scoped in the DI.